# How to simulate unicode text entry to a form

Tags: c#, unicode, input, simulator

I have wrote an application that user can register custom global hotkeys. And when these hotkeys pressed they send given text to active form. I am using [InputSimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) libray to do this. But when I tried to make this app write text that includes unicode characters (For example: "Ə" in Azerbaijani alphabet) it writes "?" instead. I replaced this char with "\u0259" and other hex codes for this Charachter (And others like "Ü","Ö","Ğ","Ş","Ç"). But nothing changed. I cant fint other libraries support unicode to do this simulation process.

I'm using WindowsForms. I hope you will help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with the font you are using on the form; make sure it is a unicode font (e.g. Arial Unicode MS).

Comment: I am using unicode font. I can write "Ə" without this app. So it is not font problem.

Comment: If you're getting "?" for "Ə", the font your *application* is using has no glyph for "Ə". Make sure your font is Unicode-capable *and* contains the Azerbaijan glyphs. The newer version of my company's main product is using Arial Unicode (available from Microsoft or Ascender Corp), which doesn't specifically support Azerbaijani, but might be part of the Turkish language support.

Comment: No, glyphs that cannot be displayed by a font are replaced by a diamond.  A question mark is always an encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the internals of the library, and the kernel of the problem should lie in the function [`InputBuilder.AddCharacter`](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/58413#1214487), where characters are translated to `WM_KEYUP`/`WM_KEYDOWN` messages; however, it seems to do its work nicely according to the documentation of `SendInput` and of the [`KEYBDINPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

My suspect is that, being `wScan` a `WORD` parameter, it cannot support Unicode characters outside the BMP, but this wouldn't explain why your character (that should *definitely* lie inside it) isn't inserted correctly.

Another suspect is that the target application doesn't process correctly those "special" `WM_KEYUP`/`WM_KEYDOWN` (that have as wParam `VK_PACKET` and are translated in a `WM_CHAR` with black magic); do you have that problem with every application?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is posted here:
http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/discussions/214858

The dev said he "should be releasing soon" in November... I'm currently looking into editing the .dll myself. Looks like only 2 lines of changes. I'll post again if I figure out how.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried that fix but it didn't work for me. Maybe that was for an older version or I did something wrong. This class is still the best solution for me. If you fix this unicode support problem please notify me. Thank you again :)

Comment: Yeah it didn't work for me either, can't figure it out. The fix seems so simple but it appears to be for an older version? :/